# Tkinter Button Appearing Behind Old button instead of Front

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Background: I am making a Battleship game when the users click an AI battleship, I want to change the button from default color to an "explosion" .PNG.

Now here's the problem. So I have this grid of buttons, and I would like to know how do I place the new button in front of an old one? It's working for one of the grids of buttons but not on one.

More specifically in AI Underwater and Player Underwater. [This image should help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmt4M.jpg)

So this is the code to update the button.

```
def draw_new_button_hit(row, column):


    global redraw_gameboard
    global Player
    global AI_player
    global AI_surface_cell
    global player_underwater_cell

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    rel_path = "explode.png"
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path))
    image = image.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    imtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, master = redraw_gameboard)

    new_button = Button(redraw_gameboard,
                        image=imtk,
                        height = 20+10, 
                        width = 20+16,
                        command= already_shot, state = DISABLED)

    new_button.image = imtk

    new_button.lift()
    new_button.grid(row = row, column = column)
```

And this works for AI & Player SURFACE. But not Underwater Boards.

This is the code for creating my board.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
import os 
from random import randint
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Player = {'Carrier':[(1, 11, 1), (1, 12, 1), (1, 13, 1), (1, 14, 1)], 'Submarine': [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0)]}
AI_player = {'Carrier':[(12,12,1), (12,13,1), (12,14,1), (12,15,1)], 'Submarine': [(12,6,0), (12,7,0), (12,8,0)]}


button_height = 2
button_width = 4

def redraw_boards():
    global redraw_gameboard
    global Player
    global AI_player

    Player["Player Surface"] = {}
    Player["Player Underwater"] = {}
    AI_player["AI Surface"] = {}
    AI_player["AI Underwater"] = {}

    redraw_gameboard = tk.Tk()
    redraw_gameboard.title("Battleship Game")
    redraw_gameboard.geometry("1000x1000")
    redraw_gameboard.resizable(False, False)

    Label(redraw_gameboard, text="Player Underwater", height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)
    Label(redraw_gameboard, text="Player Surface", height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=0, column=12, columnspan=10)

    # Preparing spacings between the grids
    Label(redraw_gameboard, text="", height = 20, width = 4).grid(row=1, column=10, rowspan=10)
    Label(redraw_gameboard, text="AI Underwater", height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=10)
    Label(redraw_gameboard, text="AI Surface", height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=11, column=11, columnspan=10)
    #Label(redraw_gameboard, text="", height = 4, width = 1).grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=10)


    for i in range(12, 22):
        AI_player["AI Underwater"][i] = {}
        for j in range(10):
            AI_player["AI Underwater"][i][j] = {}
            AI_player["AI Underwater"][i][j]["Presence"] = None
            AI_underwater_cell = Button(redraw_gameboard, 
                                        height = button_height, 
                                        width = button_width,
                                        highlightbackground="#000080",
                                        command=lambda row=i, column=j, depth = 0: shoot(row, column, depth))
            AI_underwater_cell.grid(row=i, column=j)
            AI_underwater_cell.lower()

    for i in range(1, 11):
        Player["Player Underwater"][i] = {}
        for j in range(10):
            Player["Player Underwater"][i][j] = {}
            Player["Player Underwater"][i][j]["Presence"] = None
            player_underwater_cell = Button(redraw_gameboard, 
                                            height = button_height, 
                                            width = button_width, 
                                            command=cannot_shoot,
                                            highlightbackground="#000080")
            player_underwater_cell.grid(row=i, column=j)
            player_underwater_cell.lower()


    for i in range(1, 11):
        Player["Player Surface"][i] = {}
        for j in range(11, 21):
            Player["Player Surface"][i][j] = {}
            Player["Player Surface"][i][j]["Presence"] = None
            player_surface_cell = Button(redraw_gameboard, 
                                         height = button_height, 
                                         width = button_width, 
                                         command=cannot_shoot,
                                         highlightbackground="#1E90FF")
            player_surface_cell.grid(row=i, column=j) 


    for i in range(12, 22):
        AI_player["AI Surface"][i] = {}
        for j in range(11, 21):
            AI_player["AI Surface"][i][j] = {}
            AI_player["AI Surface"][i][j]["Presence"] = None
            AI_surface_cell = Button(redraw_gameboard, 
                                     height = button_height, 
                                     width = button_width, 
                                     highlightbackground="#1E90FF",
                                     command=lambda row=i, column=j, depth = 1: shoot(row, column, depth))

            AI_surface_cell.grid(row=i, column=j)


    for i in range(len(Player["Carrier"])):
        player_ship_location = Button(redraw_gameboard,
                                      height = button_height, 
                                      width = button_width, 
                                      command=cannot_shoot,
                                      highlightbackground="#2E8B57")

        player_ship_location.grid(row = Player["Carrier"][i][0], column = Player["Carrier"][i][1])

    for i in range (len(Player["Submarine"])):
        player_ship_location = Button(redraw_gameboard,
                                      height = button_height, 
                                      width = button_width, 
                                      command=cannot_shoot,
                                      highlightbackground="#2E8B57")

        player_ship_location.grid(row = Player["Submarine"][i][0], column = Player["Submarine"][i][1])

    print (redraw_gameboard.grid_slaves)
    redraw_gameboard.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to hide a button (this will have the same effect than drawing on top of it) you can call `grid_remove()` on the button. The button will not be lost. doing `button.grid()` will have it drawn again

Comment: ***how do I place the new button in front of an old one?***: Replace the image of the`Button` instead.